# Middleware in RouteCollection.yml

Tags: routes, middleware, silex

i looking for a solution to combine a route collection in Silex with middleware.I have no idea how to solve this problem. Do somebody have an idea?

```
indexGet:
    path: /chat
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::indexHtml'       }
    methods: [GET]

indexPost:
    path: /chat
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::sendMessage'}
    methods: [POST]

LoginGet:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\Logins::checkLoginData'}
    methods: [GET]

RegisterGet:
    path: /register
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\RegisterForm::showReg'}
    methods: [GET]

RegisterPost:
    path: /register
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\RegisterForm::showReg'}
    methods: [POST]

root:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::reCon' }
    methods: [GET]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add middlewares in routes config file.
Ex.:

```
indexGet:
    path: /chat
    defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::indexHtml'       }
    methods: [GET]
    options:
        _before_middlewares: [ttttt1]
        _after_middlewares: [ttttt2]
```

and define callbacks `ttttt1`, `ttttt2` in code

```
function ttttt1($request, $app) {
    echo 'ttttt1';
}
function ttttt2($request, $response, $app) {
    echo 'ttttt2';
}
```

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/middlewares.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Thank u so much for helping

Comment: can u betray me where do u this information have from? Thx